# How I can add textboxes (username, password) to Yii2 NavBar?

Tags: yii2, navbar

Is it possible to add textboxes to NavBar so that the user can enter username and password into the menubar instead of Login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a form in your navbar inside the layout.

the sample provide is for a basic form but you can use an activeForm for yii2 and relate the field to a model (user o LoginForm)

This is a part of main.php layout (in yourapp/frontend/layout )  adn add two input field at the end of navbar..

```
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <?php
        NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => 'MyBrand',
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'brandOptions' =>[
                'style' => 'font-family: palatino; font-size:24px;'
            ],
            'options' => [
                //'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
                'class' => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
        ]);

  ......


 .......
            echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => $menuItems,
            'encodeLabels' => false,
        ]);
    ?>
        <form>
          First name:
          <input  style="display: inline;" type="text" name="firstname">
          Last name:
          <input style="display: inline;" type="text" name="lastname">
        </form> 

    <?php 

        NavBar::end();
    ?>
```

Comment: I my answer is right.  please mark as accepted and if is also useful rate it as useful too..

Comment: Yes and if you find this useful too  you can rate it with the upper arrow in top left of the answer.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
 $menuItems[] = '&lt;li>'
                    . Html::beginForm($action = '', $method = '', $options = [])
                    . Html::textInput('search', '', [])
                    . Html::endForm()
                    . '&lt;/li>';
```

Before `echo Nav::widget`
That is all